# Embed YouTube with sound off

Tags: audio, youtube

How must the code below be changed to embed this YouTube with sound off?

```
<embed src="http://www.youtube.com/v/etnh6_omu0w&hl&rel=1&autoplay=1&sound=1" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" 
allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="true" width="200"></embed>
```

Comment: @Dominic Edited the question to show code.

Answer (score 17):

Here's the code as it should be:

you'll need to include this as well in the same folder this code is in:

[SWFObject.js](http://swfobject.googlecode.com/files/swfobject_2_2.zip)

That's just some helper code, I wouldn't worry about it.

code:

```
  <script type="text/javascript" src="swfobject.js"></script>    
  <div id="ytapiplayer">
    You need Flash player 8+ and JavaScript enabled to view this video.
  </div>

  <script type="text/javascript">

    var params = { allowScriptAccess: "always" };
    var atts = { id: "myytplayer" };
    swfobject.embedSWF("http://www.youtube.com/v/FSz_a_yx9hA&hl&enablejsapi=1&playerapiid=ytplayer", 
                       "ytapiplayer", "425", "356", "8", null, null, params, atts);

    function onYouTubePlayerReady(playerId) {
        ytplayer = document.getElementById("myytplayer");
        ytplayer.mute();
    }

  </script>
```

Ok I tested that code and I know it works so if you have any problems let me know, happy hacking!

Get the docs here: [YouTube Embedded Player Javascript API Reference](http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/js_api_reference.html#GettingStarted)

Answer (score 0):

<s>It doesn't work in my web browsers.</s> It said my flash player should be version 8+ But I was using flash player 9 with javascript on. I tested on both Firefox 3.11 & IE 7.

I realize, the flash player's support on Firefox is a little bit buggy (update the player several times), some flash movie may still not appear (blank), but on IE it should work fine. <s>But not in your sample code..</s> 
Correction: it works on my IE 7. 
But not in Firefox 3.11. I wonder, why flash player / SWFObject not getting along with recent firefox. Do you have any tweak or recommendation can be done to make Firefox 3 plays *all* swf well?

Comment: To be honest I'm really not sure. I would check the google code forums for answers to that question. Sorry I can't be more help. Maybe you should create a new question and see if anyone else can help?

Comment: Thanks, Shady. I have figured out my problem with Firefox: I used AdBlock Firefox add on version that disable unwanted ads. And my version was old & the discontinued one. So, by using other version of adblock (Adblock Plus) and disabled the old discontinued adblock. Suddenly my Firefox can view all of Flash movie I missed. I wonder, why I could live with this bug and didn't solve it earlier in the first place. I've missed many good Flash movie using SWFObject. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

There might be a volume parameter on the embed tag:
[Link](http://www.htmlcodetutorial.com/embeddedobjects/_EMBED.html)